# What is the most efficient way to collect HoG descriptors (ndarrays) together for processing by Kmeans

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image

In scikit image there is a feature descriptor called [HoG](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.feature.html#hog)

The code below will calculate the descriptor for a single frame "greyVideoFrame"

```
HoGDescriptor = hog(greyVideoFrame, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8),cells_per_block=(2, 2), visualise=False)
```

Which returns a flattened (using ravel) nd array, below are some properties of the individual arrays

```
('NDarray Shape', (251328,))
('NDarray Number of Dimensions', 1)
('NDarray length of 1 array element in Bytes', 8)
('NDarray Total bytes consumed by elements', 2010624)
('NDarray DataType', dtype('float64'))
```

My question is how would i collate* the results from multiple frames together which would be able to handle efficiently **10,000 results** of `shape (251328, )` .

*I'm not sure of the correct term to use here and whether I need to append or concatenate result 1, result 2,...result 10k and would welcome the communities guidance

Comment: While there are some postings about appending items to a list, my concern is the dimensional size (251,328) of the array and the number of those arrays I have would overrun any computing resources I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with h5py to store the data in a format that wasn't limited to the size of RAM available